# How to compare between 2 COUNT() SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table like this:

```
Name   Profit
==============
A       50
A       -10
A       60
```

I want to count how many data partition by Name and then I compare it with how many data that only profit. So, from the data above I will get result like this:

```
Name  Total  Profit  Percentage
===============================
A       3      2        66.7
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `GROUP BY` query should work:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Profit > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Profit,
    100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Profit > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Percentage
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Name;
```

The only part of the query which might not be self-explanatory is the summation of the `CASE` expression.  This sum tallies, for each group of records having the same name, the number of times that `Profit` has a non zero value.  This technique is called conditional aggregation, and we also reuse this sum when calculating the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat enhanced version of Tim's answer (i.e. eliminate the calculation repetition):

```
SELECT Name, Total, Profit, 100 * Profit / Total AS Percentage
FROM (SELECT Name,
             COUNT(*) AS Total,
             SUM(CASE WHEN Profit > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Profit
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY Name) q;
```

The engine may optimize the repletion, but it is mainly for readability and maintainability (in case the calculation needs to change). In this case, there is not much gain because it is only one repletion, but in cases where thee are several repetitions, this solution becomes more useful.

In case the maintainability point is not clear, let's say the definition of profitability has changed in the company and now we consider > 10 to be profitable. In Tim's query, you'll have to change every calculation from `> 0` to `> 10`. In the query above, you'll only have to change it in one place.

Comment: This does eliminate the repeated conditional sum, but it does so at the cost an additonal subquery.  In general, we would only ever go with this option for readability of code, but probably not for performance.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I was talking about readability and also maintainability. That's why I said "**somewhat** enhanced version". See my clarification.

Comment: Do `100 * Profit / Total AS Percentage` instead.

Comment: BTW, doesn't SQL Server end up optimizing both queries to the same execution?

Comment: @jarlh Oops! That's just a copy/paste mistake. Corrected. Thanks for the note. As for the optimization, possibly, I haven't tried it. But even if the two solution don't end up with the same execution, the performance difference is negligible. The goal of this solution is readability and maintainability like I explained, not performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @t table
(
    Name varchar(10),
    Profit int
)
insert into @t
values('A',50),('A',60),('A',-10)

SELECT
    Name,
    Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Profit>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Total = COUNT(1),
    Average = (SUM(CASE WHEN Profit>0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/COUNT(1))*100
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, both are same